# MySQL - 3 updates need to be run 1 by 1 in Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have to run 3 updates in one procedure. My 3 separates update work well when I call them one bye one in php but I would like to have them regroup to perform only one call. My procedure is

```
create
    definer = root@localhost procedure UpdateScorePredictionParticipant(IN predPts int(10), IN predId int(10), IN partId int(10))
BEGIN
  UPDATE predictions
  SET pred_pts = @predPts
  WHERE pred_game_id = @predId and participant_id = @partId;

  UPDATE ranking
  SET pts_wildcard = (SELECT sum(pred_pts)
  FROM predictions
  INNER JOIN games g on predictions.pred_game_id = g.id
  WHERE predictions.participant_id = @partId)
  WHERE participant_id = @partId;

  UPDATE ranking
  SET total = (pts_wildcard+pts_conference+pts_division+pts_pred_sb+pts_sb)
    WHERE participant_id = @partId;

END;
```

How could I perform those 3 updates 1 by 1 but in the same call.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question! What's wrong with your current stored proc? What do you mean by executing the statements one by one?

Comment: For some reason, my second and third update where not done... but I have done slaakso suggestion and it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are updating 3 different tables, you will need to do three separate updates. However if you put them in a procedure, you only need call the procedure from the PHP code.

To fix the procedure code, remove the `@` from the used parameter names.

It is also a good practice to prefix the parameters, so they will not mix up with the column names.

Last thing you can do, is to use a transaction inside the procedure, so all updates complete or if some of them fail, none of them gets done. This ensures the atomicity in the operation.

```
create procedure UpdateScorePredictionParticipant(
in_predPts int, 
in_predId int, 
in_partId int
)
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE predictions
SET pred_pts = in_predPts
WHERE pred_game_id = in_predId and participant_id = in_partId;

UPDATE ranking
SET pts_wildcard = (
  SELECT sum(pred_pts)
  FROM predictions
    INNER JOIN games g on predictions.pred_game_id = g.id
  WHERE predictions.participant_id = in_partId
)
WHERE participant_id = in_partId;

UPDATE ranking
SET total = (pts_wildcard+pts_conference+pts_division+pts_pred_sb+pts_sb)
WHERE participant_id = in_partId;

COMMIT;

END
```